# Can I use some sort of local storage as a temporary holding place for getUserMedia for near-RTC?

Tags: local-storage, webrtc, getusermedia, kurento

I have a use case that doesn't exactly require real time communication, but as close as I can get it to make sure my users don't have to wait forever uploading a file after the fact.  Our site allows users to record video and audio that we then store on our server.

I moved from flash, because flash, to a WebRTC implementation with a Kurento media server.  This works super well with high quality internet connections but is relatively lacking for users with poor connectivity.

I was thinking if I could some how implement a bit of a buffer before feeding the server so that I can make up for dips in connectivity that would be ideal.  I understand this isn't what WebRTC was meant for which leads to the question of whether or not there is another solution I should look into?

Any and all suggestions are welcome and appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A buffer wont change WebRTC's realtime characteristics in the face of low bandwidth. With video for instance, WebRTC might degrade either frame rate or resolution to keep up, but no-one has proposed degrading delivery time (dropping realtime-ness). Yours is an interesting use case however.

You could use [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder). It would let you record locally and then send the data as blobs to the server with either websockets or data channels.

Here's a fiddle that works in Chrome (which does video only unfortunately) and Firefox:

https://jsfiddle.net/tmwLxjLy

It shows simple recording and then playback of the video 5 seconds later. I'll leave it as an exercise to modify it to cause a continuous 5-second delay.

Comment: Thanks Jib, that's a fantastic response!  I'll investigate MediaRecorder.  Thanks for the fiddle as well.

Comment: is there any why by which we can control this frame rate when there is lossy network detected ?