# Converting a MediaStream or MediaStreamTrack to a buffer

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Can I convert a MediaStream or MediaStreamTrack to a buffer in that way I can send it through other channels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use some sort of local storage as a temporary holding place for getUserMedia for near-RTC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972529/can-i-use-some-sort-of-local-storage-as-a-temporary-holding-place-for-getusermed)