# Video with a x second delay

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I'm looking to display, only locally, a user's webcam feed to themselves, but with a 10 second delay. Basically it would be a mirror that's delayed by 10 seconds. I know how to do all of this without the delay, but don't know the most performative strategy for adding the delay.

I've accomplished this using Max/MSP/Jitter before, but am looking to add it to a web project. Any ideas? Google has turned up nothing but info the automatic buffer.

Comment: You could [use MediaRecorder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34997248/918910).

Comment: Thank you @jib ! I have a (really) rough version of it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/stolinski/jp712Lyy/