# MediaRecorder - Is it possible to record and play at the same time?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-audio

I'm trying to build a simple audio recorder that records and plays the users voice at the same time ( synchronously ) using WebRTC and MediaRecorder. So, here is what I've done so far :

**Full Html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Audio Recorder</title>
    <style>
        audio{
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio" controls autoplay></audio>
    <button type="button" onclick="mediaRecorder.start(1000)">Start</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="mediaRecorder.stop()">Stop</button>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mediaRecorder = null,
            chunks = [],
            audio = document.getElementById('audio');

        function onSuccess( stream ) {

            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder( stream );

            audio.srcObject  = stream ;


            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function( event ) {
                chunks.push( event.data );
            }
        }

        var onError = function(err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        }

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(onSuccess, onError);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with this code is that, it plays the whole stream, and what I want is the recorded part only ( the audio recorded by the MediaRecorder ).

**Question:** Is that possible or the only option is stopping the recorder and then getting the recorded part ( 'chunks' in the code ) ?

> **Note:** A yes/no answer would be more than enough for me. Thanks.

**Code explanation :**

When you run the code, your browser asks you for permission to access your microphone :

[image]

In case, you hit allow, you will hear your voice even if you didn't click the start button, and that's because the source of the audio element is set to the whole stream .

[image]

[image]

What I want is to hear the recorded part only, when recording ( hitting the start button ), **in other words, converting the recorded part into a stream**.

**What I'm looking for :**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "the recorded part only"? When is that different from "the whole stream"?

Comment: @jib What I wanna do is somehow play what's in chunks only while recording , and as you know the stream start when the user accepts the mic request . Thank you so much.

Comment: I don't understand the difference you're after. The recording is of exactly what you hear already. What do you expect to hear different?

Comment: @jib I've added a visual explanation. Thanks again.

Comment: As to the counters, those differ per browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative. Using **stream** as **audio.srcObject** does not provide the necessary flexibility to limit **audio.duration**. You must use a **Blob** of chunks to achieve this.

The MediaRecorder works in chunks (even if you don't set the chunk duration in **mediaRecorder.start()**, hence there is no way to reliably produce audio of exact duration.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `autoplay` from your audio element, and do

```
mediaRecorder.start(1000);
audio.play();
```

and

```
mediaRecorder.stop();
audio.pause();
```

Then audio from the microphone will be audible during recording only.

You don't need to convert the recorded part to a stream. If you did, it would just introduce a delay.

OTOH, if you're trying to play back what you've already recorded, see [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34997248/918910).

Comment: you are close here is the result of what you've told me :
![result](https://i.imgur.com/YvDpebH.png)
Thank you so much

Comment: The two green conditions is all I need :-D. Idk if that's possible or not .

Comment: Please update your question. The fiddle in the other answer I link to does let you "Save Audio As...", but that's because it's playing a blob of known size (the final recording). The save option is generally not available for MediaStreams.

Comment: (up voted) and the question has been updated . Thanks a lot

Comment: In my case the audio is sent to a server. Is there a way to avoid the mouse click sound in the recorded wav file? Thanks!!